# how to compute daily skewness of S&P daily return timeseries under no other more high - frequency time series?

Tags: time-series, variance, skewness, kurtosis

As we all know , return time series marked features: fat tail or negative skewness and peakedness.  For a similar problem of variance computation, we can compute variance by garch model and other derivatives.In other words,Does we predict skewnenss like predicting variance by garch model and other derivatives ?  does the existing model for skewness exist ? According to modern fiancial  theory(investors like high return ,high skewness or positive skewness ,dislike variance ,kurtosis),we can deduce$\frac{ \partial {\text{variance}}}{\partial{\text{skewness}}}<0$ and$\frac{ \partial {\text{variance}}}{\partial{\text{kurtosis}}}>0$.and kurtosis ? Two seeming useful links:

1. http://www.portfolioprobe.com/2012/01/16/a-slice-of-sp-500-skewness-history/
2. http://blog.datapunks.com/2011/10/market-skewness/

Any comments are appreciated

Comment: anybody here?any links or thougts can be post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

skewness and kurtosis can both be predicted by models similar to garch and its derivatives.
For more details: [a new published paper here](http://www.romeo-tedongap.com/medias/paramcondskewfjpt2013final.pdf)